# 2d isometric maps in libGDX

Tags: libgdx, 2d, isometric

Im a starting game developer and I'm having some issues with how to setup a isometric 2D map. I haven't got the slightest clue in how I should accomplish that. And what would be the easiest way to do this.

EDIT:
I already have looked up tutorials but they are mostly to make 3D isometric maps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can create 2D array (array of arrays) to store map fields and draw them far to near. What is the problem exactly? Storing the map or drawing the map or something else?

Answer (score 1):

As I commented 2D array should do the trick, but check out this tutorial too:

https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-isometric-worlds-a-primer-for-game-developers--gamedev-6511

Also for editing maps check on (free) map editors. I'm using one called "Tiled" and it has support for many different map types.

https://www.mapeditor.org/